# Apache direcionando duas URLs para a mesma pasta

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, symfony

Tenho 2 projetos sf2 em pastas diferentes. Quando acesso eles pelas URLs
`localhost/projeto01` e `localhost/projeto02`m vão para mesmo local (projeto01 até mesmo quando acesso /projeto02).

Criei após isso um vhost para ver se solucionava mas não resolveu:

O problema foi antes da criação dos vhosts. Não aparece erro algum em logs da aplicação do sf2 nem do apache.

Versão Apache 2.4.6
Versão SF Symfony 2.4
Versão SO: XUbuntu 13.10

Observação: As URLs acessadas são diferentes e os diretórios são diferentes.
Ambos os projetos imprimem na view mensagens diferentes, mas estão iguais.
Mesmo acessando normalmente pelo localhost/projeto acontece o problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que ficou faltando a diretiva `NameVirtualHost *:80` em cada um dos vhosts.

Comment: Provavelmente é o NameVirtualHost *:80 mesmo, mas isso não explicaria a situação do _localhost/projeto02_ abrir o mesmo conteúdo da pasta _localhost/projeto01_ isso me deixou curioso sobre o cas, existe um .htaccess na raiz da pasta da aplicação que abre? isso poderia capturar a requisição e ocasionar este sintoma

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você está criando virtualhosts mas tentando acessar como localhost; se for isso não vai funcionar mesmo! Para o virtualhost funcionar você precisa acessar a URL pelo nome do host senão como o apache vai saber onde pegar os arquivos?

Se o que você quer é que a url `http://localhost/projeto1` acesse um diretório diferente da `http://localhost/projeto2` a forma mais simples não seria usando "aliases"?

Algo do tipo:

```
Alias /projeto1 /var/www/sort/cliente/web
<directory>
(...)
</directory>

Alias /projeto2 /var/www/sort/dashboard/web
<directory>
(...)
</directory>
```

Ou você pode manter a configuração por vhosts e colocar os nomes no /etc/hosts, algo do tipo:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost <--- ESSE JÁ DEVE EXISTIR
127.0.0.1 projeto1
127.0.0.1 projeto2
```

O acesso nesse caso ficaria `http://projeto1` e `http://projeto2`; repare que o nome do VirtualHost agora é parte da URL que, graças à edição no hosts resolve para o mesmo ip.

Answer (score 0):

No Apache 2.4, a diretiva **NameVirtualHost** entrou em desuso (deprecated).
Recomenda-se a configuração "IP-based Virtual Host": http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/ip-based.html

1. Remova **NameVirtualHost**
2. Na diretiva de "escuta", especifique as portas que deseja utilizar:
   Exemplo para a porta 80:
   `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`
3. Na tag VirtualHost, troque o asterisco pelo número IP.
   Exemplo
   `< VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 >`

Obs: O IP 127.0.0.1 é um número IP local.
Os exemplos acima são ilustrativos.

Comment: Isso é preocupante! Onde você viu que o uso de named vhosts caiu em desuso? Como fica o caso de shared hosts onde o mesmo servidor responde a "N" hosts no mesmo IP? Só a idéia alocar endereços separados para cada servidor que tenho já me dá calafrios.

Comment: Saber ler e escrever é diferente de entender o que lê e escreve.. rsrs
Leia novamente e preste bem atenção que entenderá. Faça também um pequeno esforço em pesquisar. Com duas palavras no google vc encontrará milhares de respostas.